# PHP Mysql Max+1 in same table

Tags: php, mysql

in PHP update query Max+1 is working in local but not working for me in hosting, please help

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (!empty($_POST['PaidY'])) {
    $selected_ids = array();
    foreach ($_POST['PaidY'] as $selected) {
      $selected_ids[] = $selected;
    }
    $included_ids = implode(" ", $selected_ids);
    $sql = "UPDATE fees SET Receiptno= (SELECT MAX(Receiptno) + 1 FROM fees), Paiddate= '$Paiddate', PaidY = '1' WHERE id in (" . $included_ids . ")";
    $pdo->query($sql);
    header("Location: feespaid_list.php");
  }
}
```

Receiptno= (SELECT MAX(Receiptno) + 1 FROM fees),
this part is working in local but not working for me in hosting, , i checked with a number instead of Max+1 equation that works in hosting.
Thank you

Comment: You should read about how to use prepared statements in PHP.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical diagnostic. You need to check your server logs to see if there's any errors.